# Class Definition - Identifier is Undefined

Tags: c++, undefined, default-constructor

I am working on a basic C++ program that sorts arrays using various sorting algorithms. My instructor has provided me with a unit testing class that calls my sorting class and calls different methods. When tries to create an instance of my sorting class in his tests, I get an error that says `identifier "class name" is undefined`

[image]
[image]

I thought all I needed to do in order to fix this issue was to set up a default constructor in my sorting class, but that did not fix the issue. This is my `Sorts.hpp` that I have setup.

```
#ifndef SORTS_HPP
#define SORTS_HPP

class Sorts
{
public:
    Sorts();
    void bubble(int array[], int size);
    void selection(int array[], int size);
    void quick(int array[], int size);
};

#endif
```

and  I also have the default constructor defined in the `Sorts.cpp` simply like this

```
Sorts::Sorts()
{
}
```

and this is a section of the test file that is giving me the error.

```
#include "gtest.h"
#include "Sorts.hpp"

#define SMALL 10
#define BIG 10000


TEST(SmallSort, Bubble)
{
  int* pArray = generateRandomArray(SMALL);

  printArray(pArray, SMALL);

  Sorts sorter; <--- Error being thrown here

  sorter.bubble(pArray, SMALL);

  printArray(pArray, SMALL);
  checkArray(pArray, SMALL);
}
```

I tried to solve this issue by messing around with the default constructor and defining it in the `Sorts.hpp`, but that did not fix my problem (I didn't really think it would). Any ideas?

Comment: The full, verbatim error message, including the file and line number on which it claims refuge, [should be posted in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/59120339/edit). It's important.

Comment: @WhozCraig I included the entire error message in the first paragraph and I left a note in the code saying which line the error is happening on

Comment: @BrentMB I doubt that this is an entire error message. What compiler are you using?

Comment: If that's the full, *verbatim* error message, how do you know what line number it appears from ? And it *literally* says, 'identifier "class name"' with absolutely no mention to *your* class name ? How is this being built ?

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius I am using Visual Studio. I added a screenshot of the error message.

Comment: @WhozCraig You're right, my class name is `Sorts`. Please see the attached screenshot. It is being built in Visual Studio

Comment: That's an IntelliSense error. You can ignore it; IntelliSense frequently doesn't notice changes and shows stale errors.  What happens when you try to compile (build) your project?

Comment: @1201ProgramAlarm Thank you. When I run it, it seems to work fine. I usually avoid building my program when there are pending errors since usually it just shouldn't work. Thanks for pointing this out!

Comment: @BrentMB "_I am using Visual Studio. I added a screenshot of the error message._" Consider using "Output" window for error diagnostics. Since "Error" window tends to not display complete error messages, for "simplicity". And you can copy paste from it easier.